# PyQGIS + selection

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, select

I would like to select some lines in the layer that match this condition :

the attribut A have to be the same as the value of the "for" loop where the selection is realised.

(After fixing that issue, I would like then to compare an other attribute value of the layer with the value in an other "for" loop above the previous "for" loop) 
I dont know how to do that. Here is my stard code but not optimised...

valeuruniqueC2 is an array of value

```
for value2 in valeuruniqueC2 :
  ecart = 0
  iter1 = macouche.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression (u' "%s"= '+str(value2) %feature['ATT1']))
  macouche.setSelectedFeatures( [ f.id() for f in iter1 ] )
  selection = macouche.selectedFeatures()

  for feature in selection:
   ...
```

additional informations :

I did a script that's working but produce at this end the comparison beetween each value (of the considered attribute) of the layer while I am looking for doing comparison beetween lines where the condition (value of the attribute is egal to the value of the loop) is verified... so I started to do an other way but without succeed for now.

for value2 in valeuruniqueC2 : 
   ecart = 0 
   iter1 = macouche.getFeatures() 
   for feature in iter1: 
    attri1=feature.attributes() 
    if attri1[0] == value2: 
     datetime.datetime.strptime(feature['DATE3'],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
     datetime.datetime.strptime(value1,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') 
     ecart= datetime.datetime.strptime(value1,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(feature['DATE3'],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') 
     zero= datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/1900 01:00','%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/1900 01:00','%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

```
 if ecart < zero: 
  ecart= datetime.datetime.strptime(feature['DATE3'],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') - datetime.datetime.strptime(value1,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') 
  if ecart_minN > ecart : 
   ecart_minN=ecart DHn=feature['DATE3'] 
 else: if ecart_minP>ecart : 
  ecart_minP=ecart DHp=feature1['DATE3']
```

[...]

Comment: Are you able to select the features and you just want to know how to compare them? Or are you also asking how to select the features too?

Comment: I am not able to select correctly yet

Comment: Is 'ATT1' your field name?

Comment: Yes, this is the value of the field I would like to compare with the value of the loop (value2)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.